# Core Animation not working when not root View Controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, core-animation

I have some Core Animation code that works perfectly on a root View Controller (VC1), but when I change the root to another View Controller (VC2) that segues to VC1, the animations on VC1 never runs, even though its animation methods are called. Interestingly, if I turn off animate on the segue, the core animation on VC1 works.

This is my implementation of VC1:

```
CAShapeLayer* circleLayer;

- (void)setupCircle
{
    CGPathRef circlePath = CGPathCreateWithEllipseInRect(CGRectMake(10, 40, 100, 100), nil);
    circleLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    circleLayer.path = circlePath;
    circleLayer.fillColor = [UIColor orangeColor].CGColor;
    circleLayer.strokeColor = [UIColor blueColor].CGColor;
    circleLayer.lineWidth = 10;
    [self.view.layer addSublayer:circleLayer];
}

- (void)animateCircle
{
    CABasicAnimation* circleAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"strokeEnd"];
    circleAnimation.duration = 4;
    circleAnimation.fromValue = @0;
    circleAnimation.toValue = @1;
    [circleLayer addAnimation:circleAnimation forKey:@"circleAnimation"];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self setupCircle];
    [self animateCircle];
}
```

What is the problem? Thanks.

Comment: add me to amir.ios. I want to see the actual code

Comment: Try calling [self setupCircle] and [self animateCircle] in ViewDidAppear instead of ViewDidLoad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but when I change the root to another View Controller (VC2) that
>   segues to VC1

The problem in your cycle is `viewDidLoad`, it doesn't get called *if you back from the Child VC.*

Put the stuff in the `viewWillAppear` OR `viewDidAppear`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code;

```
[self performSelector:@"setupCircle" withObject:nil afterDelay:0.1];
[self performSelector:@"animateCircle" withObject:nil afterDelay:0.1];
```